# How to use GetHBITMAP method?

Tags: gdi+, bitmap, hbitmap

I have a gdi+ bitmap, and I want to convert bitmap into HBitmap.
I write the following code.

```
    HBITMAP temp;
    Color color;
    img->GetHBITMAP(color, &temp);
```

But It do not work, How can I get a HBitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstration code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k57eh1k.aspx):

```
void DemonstrateGetHbitmapWithColor()
{
   Bitmap^ bm = gcnew Bitmap( "Picture.jpg" );
   IntPtr hBitmap = bm->GetHbitmap( Color::Blue );

   // Do something with hBitmap.
   DeleteObject( hBitmap );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of the GetHBITMAP function.